# If neutrinos were Majorana fermions, then what would be the lepton number of the neutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, majorana-fermions, leptons

Majorana particles are their own antiparticles and the lepton number of antimatter is -1 whereas for matter is +1, so if neutrinos were Majorana fermions, then what would be the lepton number of the neutrino?

Comment: The concept of "lepton number" no longer remains meaningful since the corresponding U(1) symmetry is broken

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541915